# Creating a table with 3 columns using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I was advised that the following code would create a table but nothing seems to happen?

What I am wanting is a table with question numbers in A1 B1 C1 up to 8 questions in each column. Any help appreciated.

```js
var totalQuestions;

function createSheet() {
  var sheet = "";

  totalQuestions = 8;

  sheet += "<div><table>";

  for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
    sheet += "<tr>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "A" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "B" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "C" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "</tr>";
  }

  sheet += "</table></div>";
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 98%;
}

td,
th {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 33.3%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 80, 58);
}
```

Comment: What you've posted is only generating a table and set it to a variable. Please provide more details to help others to help you.

Comment: 1. You never call the function. 2. The function never returns anything. 3. The function never changes the page. Three reasons why nothing happens. You need to solve 1. and at least one of the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the HTML text into your document. Also, do not forget to return the `sheet` at the end of the function.

See: [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
var totalQuestions;

function createSheet() {
  var sheet = "";

  totalQuestions = 8;

  sheet += "<div><table>";

  for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
    sheet += "<tr>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "A" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "B" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "<td class='question'>";
    sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "C" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
    sheet += "</td>";
    sheet += "</tr>";
  }

  sheet += "</table></div>";
  
  return sheet;
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createSheet());
```

```css
table {
  width: 98%;
}

td,
th {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 33.3%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 80, 58);
}
```

You could even create a function for this:

```js
const appendHtmlTextAsChild = (htmlText, parentElement = document.body) => {
  parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlText);
};

appendHtmlTextAsChild(createSheet());
```

### Update

You could simplify this with a template literal:

```js
const range = (n, valueOrFunction) => (arr =>
  typeof valueOrFunction === 'function'
    ? arr.fill(null).map((v, i) => valueOrFunction(i))
    : arr.fill(valueOrFunction))(new Array(n));

const rangeMap = (n, valueOrFunction) => range(n, valueOrFunction).join('');

const appendHtmlTextAsChild = (htmlText, parentElement = document.body) =>
  parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlText);

const createQuestionSheet = (questions, choices) => `
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        ${rangeMap(questions, question => `
          <tr>
            ${rangeMap(choices, choice => `
               <td class="question">
                <div class="questionNumber">
                  ${String.fromCharCode(65 + choice) + (question + 1)}
                </div>
              </td>
            `)}
          </tr>
        `)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
`;

appendHtmlTextAsChild(createQuestionSheet(8, 4));
```

```css
table {
  width: 98%;
}

td,
th {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 33.3%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 80, 58);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had a button to call function in HTML just forgot to add it on here. So all that was missing is the return  sheet?

Comment: I guess, because that is how you get the text to return from the function.